# Given two relations R, S on a Set X (so that R, S ⊆ X . X) : Prove or disprove, If R and S is transitive, then so is R ∪ S

Tags: relations

How would I go about solving this problem? Usually there is some set A, where you could deduce transitivity. But This is on the relation X times X

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MathStackExchange.

A binary relation $R$ on a set $X$ is a subset of $X\times X$.

The relations $R = \{(1,2)\}$ and $S=\{(2,1)\}$ are transitive, but the union $R\cup S = \{(1,2),(2,1)\}$ is not since $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ are missing.